# Finding a function for $4$ dimension data set

Tags: interpolation, math-software, data-analysis

I've got a bunch of data with integer values for let's say variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and an also integer value $Y$ for each set of $X_{1-3}$.
My goal would be to find something like a formula that would show the mathematical operations between the variables $X_{1-3}$ to get the value of $Y$, with the help of computer software. Kind of like reverse-engineering a function into a formula to be able to calculate the value for any $X_{1-3}$ values, or even plot it.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand this process is called interpolation for points in between and extrapolation for points outside my data range. However, since with that I have zero experience, I cannot be sure, especially considering almost every article about those already had a certain function to interpolate, and didn't work with a data set.

So can anyone point a newbie like me in the right direction, and perhaps suggest some software for doing that? My idea was *MATLAB*, since I have access to a student's licence of it, but if it can't do it I'm open for other suggestions as well.

EDIT: Some additional info that I forgot to mention, and may help: all the variables have positive sign, and may have constant multipliers (a*X1, etc...).

PS: never talked about maths in English before so apologies if something is incorrect :)

Comment: Since you have discrete integer values that you're trying to predict, I would call this, in the language of machine learning, a classification problem. The standard go-to model for classification is logistic regression, though it might not give you the best results. It's probably the best-understood algorithm.

Comment: I see, and thank you for getting that straight. I would assume in case of machine learning it would take a lot more data than what I currently have. I have around 100 sets of measurements, but from what I've heard these AI-based solutions require tens of thousands, is that correct?

Comment: Well, that depends on the data, actually! Sometimes, there comes a point where more data doesn't help all that much. And over-fitting is a constant problem. Definitely recommend logistic regression to start you off.

Comment: I've looked into logistic regression a bit, with some descriptions and examples I've found on various websites, but it seems to me that's more like some predictive analysis or probability calculation, which isn't really what I'm looking for. The value of Y is always the same for unchanged values of X1-3 in my case. Am I getting something wrong about the method Adrian suggested?

Comment: The fact that logistic regression is often used for prediction doesn't change the fact that the process is well-suited to finding an unknown integer function of various variables. It does calculate probabilities, and the base algorithm is only set up to find the probability that something is $0$ or $1$. But you can do various tricks to make it a multi-label classifier, which is, according to how I read your question, what you want.